# Making a YouTube video player that plays videos randomly from a list server side

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, youtube

I want to make an embedded YouTube video that is randomly chosen from a predefined list and when it ends, to play another random video from the same list an so on.

It's relatively easy to do that with a YouTube playlist and scripting to make the list to shuffle the videos instead of playing in the given order, but I have two issues with making that:

- As for now to my knowledge, the embedded YouTube playlists only can contain 200 videos, even thought the actual limit seems to be 5000.
- More importantly, even if I actually use a YouTube playlist to define the list, I don't want to expose it to the end used (even if only shows in the code) as I want to mantain the "surprise" factor while people watch the videos.

Hence, I try to just make a predefined list that loads on the server side with PHP. I know very little of this kind of programming, so I have made some tests based on stuff I had done before along some stuff I can find on the web, yet I can't get it to work as I want.

First, I did a .php file that chooses a YouTube ID at random out of an string (the method can improve, yet that may be outside the scope of the question)

```
<?php
$input = array("kfchvCyHms", "UiyDmqO59QE", "PkVbF9DmtSw");
echo $input[array_rand($input)];
```

Then in the main page, I load the given YouTube ID given in the file and try to blend with a generated player:

```
//JQuery is loaded in the head.
<div id="player"></div>
<script src="http://www.youtube.com/player_api"></script>

<script>
//This creates a variable out of the page content (a single YouTube ID in this case)
var ching
$.get("testytid.php", function( my_var ) {
ching=my_var;
}, 'html');

    // create youtube player
    var player;
    function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '390',
          width: '640',
        videoId: 'tAg5vLb3ZEs', //the default "videoId" should be random too, but I can't get that to work.
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
    }

    // autoplay video
    function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();
    }

    function playNewVideo(id){
      player.loadVideoById(ching); //loads the random ID given by the .php file
      event.target.playVideo();
      playNewVideo(ID)
    }

    // when video ends
    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {        
        if(event.data === 0) { 
          playNewVideo();
        }
    }
</script>
```

It don't work because:

- I can't get to make the first video is random too and
- The "random" video is just the first one the .php page gives, as is never reloaded through this method.

Any ideas of how I can improve this?

Comment: is the random selection of the next single video done on client or server ?

Comment: Done on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added some comments against updates/changes. This assumes youtube setup is working and jQuery >= 3.0 for `.done`

```
function GetNextVideoFromServer() {
    $.ajax({
        url : "testytid.php",
        cache : false
    })
    .done(function (data) {
        console.log(data); // you might want to check this first. the data returned should just be a single id.
        playNewVideo(data); // call the play function
    });
}

// create youtube player
var player;
function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
            height : '390',
            width : '640',
            videoId : 'tAg5vLb3ZEs', //the default "videoId" should be random too, but I can't get that to work.
            events : {
                'onReady' : onPlayerReady,
                'onStateChange' : onPlayerStateChange
            }
        });
}

// autoplay video
function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
}

function playNewVideo(id) {
    player.loadVideoById(id); //loads the random ID given by the .php file
    event.target.playVideo();
}

// when video ends
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data === 0) {
        GetNextVideoFromServer();
    }
}
```